# Making a simple Log class

Tags: c++, class, linker

I'm trying to make this simple Log class and getting linker issue when compiling, could anyone tell me what this mean?

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)   Log C:\Users\Documents\Code Projects\Log\Log\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)*

Log.h

```
#pragma once
class Log {
public:
    enum Level
    {
        LevelError, LevelWarning, LevelInfo
    };

    void SetLogLevel(Level level);
    void Error(const char* message);
    void Warn(const char* message);
    void Info(const char* message);

private:
    Level m_LogLevel = LevelInfo;
};
```

Log.cpp

```
#include "Log.h"
#include <iostream>

void Log::SetLogLevel(Level level) {
    m_LogLevel = level;
}

void Log::Error(const char* message) {
    if (m_LogLevel >= LevelError)
        std::cout << "[ERROR]: " << message << std::endl;
}

void Log::Warn(const char* message) {
    if (m_LogLevel >= LevelWarning)
        std::cout << "[WARNING]: " << message << std::endl;
}

void Log::Info(const char* message) {
    if (m_LogLevel >= LevelInfo)
        std::cout << "[INFO]: " << message << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It means that you don't have a `main()` function?

Comment: You're right, thanks Sam!

Comment: @JohnFilleau You can be a little less sibylline ;-)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Y0dGHkAkIY

Comment: you prob. want to compile that as a library and not as an executable, then you don't need a `main`